# Getting started with nightwatch.js

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

Can anyone provide me with a detailed explanation on how to setup nightwatch and start writing browser tests? I have searched for such information online and was unable to find it. The nightwatch.js website had good information about various nightwatch command line commands, but not about actually setting up a nightwatch project, which is what I am having trouble with.

Specifically, I do not have a good understanding of the various files that come with installation of nightwatch, and how I am supposed to use them.

Comment: http://nightwatchjs.org/guide Is a good guide. You should install night watch using '-g' then you will need to create a nightwatch.json file in the directory that your project is in. Make sure you read any errors that you see in the terminal during the process.

Answer (score 13):

### *Step-by-Step Beginner's Tutorial*

We needed an ***up-to-date, well-researched*** *and* ***maintained tutorial*** for Nightwatch for our team so we wrote one: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-nightwatch

[image: Codeship]
[image: Dependency Status]
[image: devDependency Status]
[image: contributions welcome]

We (*highly*) *recommend* using a `nightwatch.conf.js` (**.js**) file for configuring Nightwatch because (*unlike a **.json** file*) it allows you leave in-line comments to your fellow developers (*i.e avoid "WTF" moments by communicating*) and to *evolve* your configuration with variables & functions as needed.

Also, we prefer to **install Nightwatch** (*and its required dependencies*) ***locally*** so it's *clear* to everyone *exactly* what is required to run the project and which *versions* we are using.

Using the [`selenium-download`](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-nightwatch#install-selenium-download) module will download the latest versions of Selenium Standalone Server and Chromedriver (*both required to run a basic Nightwatch test*) for your OS and means you will be **up-and-running *much faster***.

Rather than including the whole tutorial *here* we invite you to Star/Fork it on GitHub: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-nightwatch#step-by-step-tutorial

Feedback / questions / updates / improvements are *always* welcome!

Comment: This isn't quite working for me.  The problem I'm having is that selenium-download isn't actually grabbing the packages and placing them into the bin directory specified.  I'm also a little confused why you're not just calling the nightwatch command from the root directory i.e. `nightwatch --config nightwatch.conf.js` and instead using the following `node_modules/.bin/nightwatch --config nightwatch.conf.js`.  It should be accessible from the project root.

Comment: Hi @Andre, the _reason_ for using `node_modules/.bin/nightwatch` is to make it _clear_ to the team that we are not using a "_global_" version but rather the `nightwatch` that is installed _locally_ for the project. you can use `nightwatch --config nightwatch.conf.js` if you prefer. both work fine.

Comment: Also, with regards to `selenium-download` can you please raise an issue on GitHub so we can help debug: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-nightwatch/issues StackOverflow comments aren't great for detailed trouble-shooting. thanks!

Comment: I've having the same issue with selenium-download not putting the chromdriver and selenium server into the bin, has this been addressed yet?

Comment: @Kode_12 yes if you're having issues, please raise on GitHub: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-nightwatch/issues  with as much detail as you can so we can help debut. StackOverflow comments are not a _great_ place to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 6):

You need basiclly **two things**:

- The `nightwatch.json` file in the root of your project
- And `nightwatch` installed (`npm install -g nightwatch`).

After that you use it on the command line [as described in the documentation here](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#runner-options) and it will automatically grab your `nightwatch.json` file and run your tests based on the `default` [`test_setting`](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#config-test-settings).

I opened up [an issue](https://github.com/beatfactor/nightwatch/issues/354) to add a `nightwatch init` command, so the setup of the `nightwatch.json` file is easier.

#### Further reading

- [How to setup `nightwatch.json`](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#settings-file)
- [Github Repository](https://github.com/beatfactor/nightwatch)

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this step-by-step method to get better understanding 
[Nightwatch.js Part 1](https://www.codementor.io/johnkennedy/e2e-testing-with-nightwatch-part-one-b44jzd6mv)
[Nightwatch.js Part 2](https://www.codementor.io/johnkennedy/e2e-testing-with-nightwatch-part-two-b57uwf375)

Answer (score -2):

one big problem for users "is not worked on count 1-2-3".

so we find many-many-many times our all internet :)

and.

1) nightwatch is installed (by .rpm, .deb, npm, downloaded). is haven't questions

2) is worked by execution "nightwatch" on CLI

3) but where wunderbar example?????????????
of course, on internet!

4) by my bad memory and catalog list in simple test:
- create catalog
- create in catalog 2 dirs:

- bin for web-drivers (add chromedriver, selenium-server-standalone as minimum)
- tests for tests

5) we need this simple config - nightwatch.json in catalog (use any simple which access have)

6) create-copy-paste any simple test in test catalog (it's one on planet :)

7)it's all, run in catalog by CLI: **nightwatch**

you need only this? for first time, before documentation readings?   ;)

Answer (score -3):

```
$ npm install -g yo
$ npm install -g generator-selenium-nightwatch
$ yo selenium-nightwatch
$ npm install
$ npm test
```